# jQuery scrollTop() returns 0 for all elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, scroll, angular-ui-router

At my job we have a one page site I created with AngularJS.
We're using the ui-router plugin (version 0.2.0).
Recently I've noticed that when moving from one state to another, the window isn't scrolled to the top.
I even tried to scroll it to the top manually using jQuery's `scrollTop()` function on every state change (using the `$stateChangeSuccess` event). But it didn't work.

So I started investigating, and I've noticed that `scrollTop()` is returning 0 for every element on the page.
Not only that, but when I print the `window.scrollY` to the console I get 0 (no matter where I'm at on the page). Not only in my code, but even if I just write it in the chrome dev tools console.

I've written several apps with AngularJS and ui-router, and it only happens in this particular one.

I've checked to see if I have overwritten the `scrollTop()` function or even the `window.scrollY` field, but haven't found anything.

I've tried using the `ui-view` with `autoscroll="true"` and `autoscroll="false"`, but it didn't make a difference.

I also tried giving the `html` and the `body` elements `height:100%`, and I also tried it without. But nothing.

I really don't know what to do next.

I wasn't able to reproduce the problem, but if you think there is any code I should post here that could  be of any help, I'll be glad to do that.

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

I've run this function on the console:

```
var l = $('*').length;
for(var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    var elem = $('*:eq(' + i + ')');
    if(elem.scrollTop() > 0) {
        console.log(elem, elem.scrollTop());
    }
}
```

The function printed out only one element with it's top scroll.
The element is a wrapping div that holds the whole content and the main view (I have nested views in my app).
If I use `scrollTop(0)` on this element I get what I wanted, but it only deals with the symptom, and not the real problem.

Comment: What gives you `$(window).height()`, expected result?

Comment: @A.Wolff Thanks for the comment! I actually get a varying value. I think it depends on the window size (with console open, or closed, etc...)

Comment: AFAIK, scrollTop would always returns 0 if none or not correct DOCTYPE is set on the page, but then still AFAIK, `$(window).height()` should always returns 0. Seems like then not your issue here.

Comment: I didn't know that, it's good to know, thanks! However, I am using the html5 standard `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

Comment: Based on your edit: IS there even a problem? It seems to me you get the correct results: your one container that can scroll/is scrolled (ok this is an assumption) is also the one that correctly returns scrollTop() != 0. I would suggest your only 'problem' is that apparently Angular tries to put scrollTop(0) on your document, which is kind of an assumption, since having a content container like yours is not uncommon.

Comment: I don't know why, but the problem is related to `angular-route`. I've got a similar problem with a single page app. Inside the `partials` I cannot set the `scrollTop()` of an element, while in the main page (not inside a `partial`) it works fine.

Comment: Hey @Mike, I ran the function I posted on the chrome dev console. The page has already been loaded. The call to `scrollTop()` I made in my code was also called after the page has loaded, since this is a single page app.

Comment: I guess @Hans is right. Thanks Hans for the comment! But like I said, it does only solve the symptom. I have other, very similar, single-page apps which don't have this problem. AngularJs (with ui-router) usually scrolls the window to the top on state change.

Comment: Like @Atropo said, there's a nested view issue. Usually in angularJS (with the additional use of ui-router), when changing states, the window is scrolled to the top.
I guess it has something to do with my nested views.
I'll try to play with and come back with an answer.

Comment: @user891850 I've just posted a question with my similar problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22176305/set-the-scrollbar-position-with-angularjs maybe we can find a solution.

Comment: Hey @Atropo, I know it's been a while, but Hans was actually right, so I gave an answer (down below) and solution. I hope it helps you if it's your case as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Hans commented, there wasn't actually a problem.
I had a wrapping element, that was positioned `absolute` with:

```
top:0;
bottom:0;
left:0;
right:0;
overflow:auto
```

So The window's `scrollTop` was always 0, and the scrollbar actually belonged to the wrapping element.

Since I could't get rid of the wrapping element's positioning, I used ui-router's `$stateChangeSuccess` event, and manually scrolled the wrapping element to the top.

Answer (score 2):

From the console, try

```
console.log(frames)
console.log(frames.top.scrollY)
```

If window.scrollY is showing 0, then the reference frame must not be the window.  Do you have any iframes on the page?  console.log of frames will show the list of frames on the page.
Hope that helps.

Comment: I don't have any iframes on the page. I tried what you said on the console, on the first line i got only one window element (I guess my window), and the second gave me 0. I've also edited the question and added some test results. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

My code is happend this problem too, and I found a body{overflow: hidden;} is the reason, I remove "overflow: hidden;" and all is well.