# Can't get scroll position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I have a page whose body is scrolling. That is, a scroll event listener on *body* works. However, scroll listeners on *window* and *document* does not fire.

The problem is, even though body is scrolling, $("body").scrollTop() returns 0 all the time. I looped through ALL the children of body and none of them has scrollTop() greater than 0. Some of the children has overflow: hidden but that should not affect scrollTop I guess.

I removed height: 100% as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12788487/document-scrolltop-always-returns-0) question and I've also gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22173454/jquery-scrolltop-returns-0-for-all-elements) question.

And I made sure it is indeed *body* that is scrolling by setting its overflow as hidden - the scroll bar disappeared. And I also tried attaching scroll listeners on every container div in the application - none of them fired. So it is indeed the *body* that is scrolling and for some weird reason jquery scrollTop() returns 0 for all the elements.

And yes, I tried accessing document.body.scrollTop - still 0.

Any hints as to what might be causing this issue will be received with a LOT of gratitude. Been stuck here for a while. Thanks :)

**EDIT**: document.documentElement.scrollTop also returns 0. $(document).scrollTop() - returns 0.
!DOCTYPE html is also set.

**EDIT 2:** Strangely enough, I can't also scroll by setting scrollTop on body. That is, $('body').scrollTop(500) does nothing!

**EDIT 3:**: 
My jquery function:

```
$("body").on("scroll", function(){
    var children = $("body").children();
    $("body").scrollTop(800);
    for(var i=0; i<children.length; i++){
        if($(children[i]).scrollTop() > 0){
            console.log("children: " + i);
            console.log("val: " + $(children[i]).scrollTop());
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Have you tried `$(window).scrollTop()` ?

Comment: show your jquery method.

Comment: @Shvelo Yeah. I tried that as well. Still 0.

Comment: @JohnReyM.Baylen console.log never hits. And scrollTop for body is never set as 800. From the console, I even tried document.body.scrollTop = 300. It would still be 0!

Comment: have you tried `$('html, body').scroll(function() { // code here })` ?

Comment: @JohnReyM.Baylen That would hardly make a difference I think. I found the problem. There was an additional height: 100% coming from another css file that was causing the problem. I totally missed it since it was way down in the css inspector. Now I want to shoot myself for missing this. Arghh!!!. Thanks a lot guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a height: 100% coming from another css file. Solved it by setting height: auto.